# How save a Matplotlib figure with Pickle in a Pyqt5 environment?

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt, save, load, pickle

I'm facing an issue and I cannot get rid of it.
I'm trying to use the Pickle package in order to save a matplotlib figure to replot it if i want to.
So far I have the below code which open a Qt window and plot some curves in it if the 'if' condition in `lfpViewer.__Init__()` is 1 (I put 0 only to check the pickle load function).
So I added, to the toolbar, two buttons where I can save a .pickle of the current figure or load a .pickle from a previous figure.

```
import pickle
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import os
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar


class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.color = self.centralWidget.palette().color(QPalette.Background)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.plotview = QGroupBox(" ")
        self.layout_plotview = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mascenelfp = lfpViewer(self)
        self.layout_plotview.addWidget(self.mascenelfp)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.layout_plotview)


class lfpViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(lfpViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(self.parent.color))# self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(200, 200, 200)))
        self.figure = plt.figure(facecolor=[self.parent.color.red()/255,self.parent.color.green()/255,self.parent.color.blue()/255]) #Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self) 
        self.save_button = QPushButton()
        self.save_button.setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join('icons','SaveData.png')))
        self.save_button.setToolTip("Save Figure Data")
        self.toolbar.addWidget(self.save_button)
        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.saveFigData)
        self.load_button = QPushButton()
        self.load_button.setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join('icons','LoadData.png')))
        self.load_button.setToolTip("Load Figure Data")
        self.toolbar.addWidget(self.load_button)
        self.load_button.clicked.connect(self.loaddatapickle)
        if 0:
            t=np.arange(1000)
            self.axes_l=self.figure.add_subplot(311)
            self.axes_l.plot(t, np.sin(2*3.14*100*t))
            self.axes_Y=self.figure.add_subplot(312)
            self.axes_Y.plot(t, np.cos(2*3.14*100*t))
            self.axes_Yi=self.figure.add_subplot(313)
            self.axes_Yi.plot(t, np.tan(2*3.14*100*t))


        self.canvas.setGeometry(0, 0, 1600, 500 )
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def loaddatapickle(self):
        fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Load Data', '', 'pickle (*.pickle)')
        if  (fileName[0] == '') :
            return
        fileName = str(fileName[0])
        filehandler = open(fileName , 'rb')
        self.figure = pickle.load(filehandler)
        filehandler.close()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.parent.parent.processEvents()
        return

    def saveFigData(self):
        fileName = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,'Save Figure Data', '', 'pickle (*.pickle)')
        if  (fileName[0] == '') :
            return
        fileName = str(fileName[0])
        file_pi = open(fileName, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self.figure, file_pi, -1)
        file_pi.close()
        return


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The save seems works (well, at least, I have a file), but the load button do absolutly nothing !
Even If I have a .pickle file, I don't know if pickle save the correct binary of the figure because when I load the pickle file in debug mode, I get lot of red stuff.
Look for the below image :

[image]

If I do the code without PyQt5, it works fine, for instance, with the below code:

```
import pickle
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def loaddatapickle():
    filehandler = open('test.pickle' , 'rb')
    figure = pickle.load(filehandler )
    filehandler.close()
    return  figure

def saveFigData(figure):
    file_pi = open('test.pickle', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(figure , file_pi, 1)
    file_pi.close()
    return


figure = plt.figure( ) #Figure()

Save= 0

if Save==1:
    t=np.arange(1000)
    axes_l=figure.add_subplot(311)
    axes_l.plot(t, np.sin(2*3.14*100*t))
    axes_Y=figure.add_subplot(312)
    axes_Y.plot(t, np.cos(2*3.14*100*t))
    axes_Yi=figure.add_subplot(313)
    axes_Yi.plot(t, np.tan(2*3.14*100*t))
    saveFigData(figure)

else:

    figure=loaddatapickle()
    plt.show()
```

If somebody have an idea of what is going on here, please tell me !
Have a nice day.

Comment: The issue could be due to the fact that pickle save a matplotlib.figure.Figure instead of a matplotlib.pylab.Figure. So It cannot be handle when I relaod the self.figure from the pickle file?

Comment: type(plt.figure()) returns matplotlib.figure.Figure as well, they are both the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure if this solves the problem you are facing, but let's give it a try. I need to mention, I don't have QT5 available and I'm working with python 2.7 and matplotlib 2.0.0. But the solution here might be valid for general cases.

When adapting the program to pyqt4 and running it, I found out that the pickling works fine. Also the unpickling did not throw any error, so I suspected that there might be a problem of displaying the unpickled figure.

What turns out to allow loading the figure is to not only load the figure into `self.figure` but to **recreate the canvas with this unpickled figure** and newly add it to the layout:

```
def loaddatapickle(self):
    #needed to change some stuff here, since in Qt4 the dialog directly returns a string
    fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Load Data', '' )
    if  (fileName == '') :
        return
    fileName = str(fileName)
    filehandler = open(fileName , 'rb')
    self.figure = pickle.load(filehandler)
    filehandler.close()
    # remove the old canvas
    self.layout().removeWidget(self.canvas)
    # create a new canvas
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
    # add the new canvas at the position of the old one
    self.layout().addWidget(self.canvas, 1)
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.parent.parent.processEvents()
    return
```

Of course it would be better to directly update the canvas with the new figure, but I haven't found any way to do that.